# Read standard performance monitor statistics in Python 2 or 3?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, python-2.x, performance-monitor

How can I read widows performance statistics in Python: cpu time, disk time, memory usage, ... All data available in standard Windows performance monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Winstats is a Python module which wraps the Windows C API. It should be able provide an interface to access all the properties you listed.

https://pypi.org/project/winstats/